# Unable to switch " Application " themes using Tweaks in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, themes, gnome-tweaks

I am not sure whether it has anything to do with installing the `Orchis theme`. But around that time, this issue started. I am able to switch icons, cursors and shell themes using the`Tweaks` tool in `22.04`. But even though I am able to change the " Application " theme to Adwaita or even Yaru Dark in the `Tweaks` tool, it won't change in real.

I tried logout and login, shutdown and start, without success.

Strangely, I am able to use the option in the `Settings` to switch between Yaru Light and Yaru Dark. Currently, that is the only way I can switch themes and is limited to Yaru light and Yaru Dark options.

Would be nice if someone can help me fix this issue.

Update 1:

I can confirm it is due to Orchis install script. No solutions found yet though.

Comment: use `Extension Manager` and install `User Themes`

Comment: Thanks @24601 , are you referring to `Extensions` app? Not sure where to find `Extension Manager`.

Comment: I have `User Themes` listed in `Extensions` app, just checked.

Comment: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/manage-gnome-extensions-ubuntu-2204/

Comment: Thanks. I installed Extension Manager and selected Yaru, not changing. Tried shutdown and start, no luck.